# How do I fix a circuit that keeps blowing a capacitor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, electrolytic-capacitor

I have an aftermarket AC>DC wall wart that was made in China and there is an electrolytic capacitor in the circuit that blows about every 2 years and it just happened again.  I'm tired of replacing them.  What should I do to improve the circuit so this doesn't happen a 4th time?

*More info*
It's a fairly complicated circuit with many components for a 5v wall wart.  It has an IC, several resistors, ceramic capacitors, extra diodes, transistor, and individual diodes as a rectifier.  Not sure why so many components.  The original was 1000uf 10v and I replaced with an on-hand branded 1000uf 16v from a motherboard.  It looks like there is another capacitor exactly the same but now both the previously replaced and 2nd identical one are bulged.  They practically touch the transformer so maybe they are getting cooked.

Comment: Can you provide a schematic for the wall wart?

Comment: A picture might help give us an idea of what is geibg discussed. Generally (!) it comes down to the specification of the capacitor. If you replace a poor spec one with another, then the same failure will happen.

Comment: what circuit are you trying to improve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, a common reason for electrolytic failure is overheating; overheating is caused by excessive current.  The failure might be a sign that the loading is too high, or the design is lacking, or poor quality component was chosen.  Myself, I would just replace the supply with one that can provide more power.  If you'd rather go the repair route, try to find a capacitor that has a higher ripple current rating.  Problem is, you may have to go up in capacitance, and size, so it might not fit where it needs to go.  At least, get the highest temperature rated one you can find.  Also, use a quality brand from an reliable distributor, not some no-name part off of ebay.  There's a lot of junk out there

Comment: Thanks, I'll just replace it.  Using a higher voltage capacitor didn't seem to help and I think you're right it's getting cooked.  Nothing I can do about that.

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of possible reasons; find the real reason and fix it.

0. Don't try to establish anything with measurements it if the cap is rated for over 63V -- in that case, there's likely to be potentially fatal voltages on the cap, and if you have to ask, you probably don't know how to stay safe.
1. The capacitor is at the limit of its voltage rating (i.e., 6.3V on a 6.3V capacitor).  For long life you should choose a cap that's at least 20%, or better yet 50% over-rated.  If you're *absolutely sure* you can measure this without getting fried, check the voltage.
2. The thing is running hot, and the capacitor is over its rated temperature.  For long life you should choose a cap that's rated for higher temperature.
3. The capacitor current is higher than it can handle.  This is darned near impossible to measure, but if it's the case you can search for a cap that's rated for more current.

Probably the cheapest way to solve the problem is to get a good brand of wall wart (Cui wall-warts are great) with the same voltage and the same or higher current rating, and use it instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should expect to get much longer than 2 years out of a power supply that is properly made. So either you have a poor quality device, or it is being abused.

> I'm tired of replacing them. What should I do to improve the circuit
> so this doesn't happen a 4th time?

1. Install a capacitor with higher voltage and ripple current ratings (assuming it isn't too big to fit in the case).
2. Make sure the unit isn't running too hot due to insufficient ventilation or drawing too much current from it.
3. Replace the unreliable 'wallwart' with a better quality unit or and/or one with higher power rating.

Answer (score 1):

You must be aware for one thing.
There is capacitor for decoupling ...

And there is capacitor for filtering rectified current !
This later type is specified for an RMS current !

The capacitor for "decoupling" is not intended for "filtering" !
Even if this is functional for "some time" which can be "long" or "short" ...
Some time ... very short !
So, choose a capacitor on which "ripple current" (in rms A) is indicated ...
If not, don't use !

Another thing to take care is ... the "functional time".
It is specified in hours ... (10 000 hours -> 420 days ...)

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with a similarly rated tantalum cap.

Tantalum are considerably more expensive but they aren't nearly so prone to aging as electrolytic are.

Comment: But more spectacular when they fail

Answer (score 0):

If this is part of an LC filter, you could increase the L. Inductors are  important factors for cost of cheap AC-DCs. So they might have been selected at the lowest end. You can also try adding a ceramic cap in parallel that has maximum 1/10ths of the capacitance of the electrolytic. That could take some of the high frequency ripple off the electrolytic.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look for a high temperature device - many caps are rated at 85C but you can get 105C or higher if you think that overheating might be a problem